# Replicating Java's String.hashCode() method for a cljc project

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript

I have a project which is supposed to work both as a clj and cljs project, it currently uses Java String's hashCode for hashing and I can't change this. I need to find a way to implement the same solution for the cljs scenarios.

I have the required code for the javascript implemnetation of the same hashing process and I think ideally I'd like to use this function for both clj and cljs scenarios as it is the fastest way of hashing this specific way that I know of.

```
hashCode = function(stringToHash){
    let hash = 0;
    if (stringToHash.length === 0) return hash;
    let char;
    for (i = 0; i < p1.length; i++) {
        char = stringToHash.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + char;
        hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
    }
    return hash;
};
```

The other option is to recreate the hashing algorithm in pure clojure but I think this would result in worse performance. So my question is either how to either properly require this one js method into my cljc project or how to recreate the same algorithm in clojure.

Here's my `hashCode.js

```
goog.provide('hashCode');

/**
 * @param {string} stringToHash
 * @return {number}
 */
hashCode.hashCode = function(stringToHash){
    let hash = 0;
    if (stringToHash.length === 0) return hash;
    let char;
    for (i = 0; i < p1.length; i++) {
        char = stringToHash.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + char;
        hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
    }
    return hash;
};
```

which I've tried requiring in my `core.cljc` file like so `[hashCode :as hs]` to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `hashCode.js` is a Closure lib, so you can use the [`:libs`](https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options#libs) compiler option to access it. This is described in more detail on the [Dependencies](https://clojurescript.org/reference/dependencies#bundling-javascript-code) page.

(Note that there is a typo in your source; `p1` should be replaced with `stringToHash`.)

Here is an example using `:libs` to access your implementation:

```
$ clj -m cljs.main -co '{:libs ["hashCode.js"]}' -r
ClojureScript 1.10.520
cljs.user=> (require '[hashCode :as hs])
nil
cljs.user=> (hs/hashCode "hello")
99162322
cljs.user=> (hs/hashCode "abcdef")
-1424385949
```

(Note that if you use `:advanced` [`:optimizations`](https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options#optimizations), since your code makes use of `let`, you would also need to specify [`:language-in`](https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options#language-in-and-language-out) as `:es6`.)

A fairly direct conversion of that implementation to ClojureScript is:

```
(defn string-hash [s]
   (loop [i 0 h 0]
     (if (< i (.-length s))
       (let [c (.charCodeAt s i)
             h (+ (- (bit-shift-left h 5) h) c)]
          (recur (inc i) (bit-and h h)))
       h)))
```

While Closure Library ships with a string hashCode implementation that is [documented](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.string.html#hashCode) as being *similar* to Java's, it may not be suitable for your use, as it doesn't generate signed hash values:

```
cljs.user=> (goog.string/hashCode "hello")
99162322
cljs.user=> (goog.string/hashCode "abcdef")
2870581347
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t]) )

(defn str->hashcode
  "Work-alike impl of Java String.hashCode() fn"
  [str-val]
  (let [char-codes (mapv int str-val)
        step-fn    (fn step-fn [hash-in char-code]
                     (let [hash-out (+ char-code
                                      (-
                                        (bit-shift-left hash-in 5)
                                        hash-in))
                           hash-out (bit-and hash-out 0xFFFFFFFF)]
                       hash-out))
        result     (reduce step-fn 0 char-codes)]
    result))

(dotest
  (spy "hello")
  (spyx (str->hashcode "hello"))
  (spyx (.hashCode "hello"))
  )
```

with result

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.0    Java 12
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
:spy => "hello"
(str->hashcode "hello") => 99162322
(.hashCode "hello") => 99162322
```

Always remember the Clojure/ClojureSciprt CheatSheet

- http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html
- https://cljs.info/cheatsheet/

Comment: This answer should be revised to produce signed hash values like Java's hashCode. For example, `"abcdef"` should yield `-1424385949`. Also, the OP appears to desire a solution that can work in ClojureScript.